# How to color swarmplot dots depending on quartile?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to create a plot where dots are overlaid depending on whether or not they are within the 1st-3rd quartiles in seaborn. What function to use?

Something similar to the figure:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code creates a Seaborn `swarmplot` and then recolors the dots depending on their quartile. Looping through the collections created by the `swarmplot`, the y-data are retrieved. `np.percentile` calculates the borders of the quartiles and `np.digitize` calculates the corresponding quartiles. These quartiles can be used to define the color.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

sns.set(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

# cmap = plt.get_cmap('tab10')
cmap = ListedColormap(['gold', 'crimson', 'teal', 'orange'])
ax = sns.swarmplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
for col in ax.collections:
    y = col.get_offsets()[:,1]
    perc = np.percentile(y, [25, 50, 75])
    col.set_cmap(cmap)
    col.set_array(np.digitize(y, perc))
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

The same approach can be used for a `stripplot` (optionally without jitter) to create a plot similar to the one in the question.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

sns.set(style="whitegrid")
N = 200
x = np.repeat(list('abcdefg'), N)
y = np.random.normal(np.repeat(np.random.uniform(11, 15, 7), N), 1)

cmap = ListedColormap(['grey', 'turquoise', 'grey'])
ax = sns.stripplot(x=x, y=y, jitter=False, alpha=0.2)
for col in ax.collections:
    y = col.get_offsets()[:, 1]
    perc = np.percentile(y, [25, 75])
    col.set_cmap(cmap)
    col.set_array(np.digitize(y, perc))
plt.show()
```

[image: stripplot example]